# TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewManagersMetadata' of null in React Native

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-camera

Error shown:
ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'viewManagersMetadata' of null, js engine: hermes

Versions:

```
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.1",
"expo": "^46.0.0",
"expo-barcode-scanner": "~11.4.0",
"expo-camera": "~12.3.0",
```

Happen after using the expo-barcode-scanner and expo-camera

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with the same error. Just restarted my emulator and it worked. Make sure to install the pods after adding the NSCameraUsageDescription  in Info.plist